# Python | Is there a way to execute the function returned by inspect.getmembers()

Tags: python, python-3.x

My project is designed in a way that if a user wants to expand the capability of the program, he can do so by writing some functions himself and the program will index those functions automatically.

Suppose I have a function `test()` inside a class called `Test`

```
import inspect

class Test:
    def test(self):
        print('test')

for name, func in inspect.getmembers(Test):
    if not name.startswith('__'):    # For the exclusion of dunder functions
        print(type(func))
        exec(func.__code__)          # I know that we can execute the code object of a function but this isn't working
        exec(func)                   # And this ofcourse doesn't work
```

How can I execute the test function without explicitly calling it like `Test.test()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires the instance of the class, you can pass it one or an empty dict for example:

```
import inspect

class Test:
    def test(self):
        print('test')

for name, func in inspect.getmembers(Test):
    if not name.startswith('__'):    # For the exclusion of dunder functions
        print(type(func))
        func({})
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/OilyPutridCharactermapping)

The problem comes when you actually need to access attributes from the instance:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
      self.foo = 'test'
    def test(self):
        print(self.foo)
```

The same code as above will fail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    func({})
  File "main.py", line 7, in test
    print(self.foo)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

So you still will need an object that maps the same attributes and calls you need in that function (mostly a real Instance):

```
import inspect

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
      self.foo = 'test'
    def test(self):
        print(self.foo)

foo_instance = Test()

for name, func in inspect.getmembers(Test):
    if not name.startswith('__'):    # For the exclusion of dunder functions
        print(type(func))
        func(foo_instance)
```

As [here](https://repl.it/repls/GigaFlakyToolbox)